# Cognito confirming user with email link error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Attempting to setup signup with Cognito and all is nearly working perfectly except i'm getting an error of User cannot be confirmed when they click on the email verification link that is sent to them. I can see in the Cognito UI the user has a Confirmation Status of unconfirmed before clicking the link. After they click the link the confirmation status is set to Confirmed and they are good to go it's just that the below error is being shown instead of a successfully confirmed message instead?

Is there some sort of redirect happening here which is why i'm getting this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue which was hinted here -> https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/issues/219

I was opening the links through my Outlook desktop client - It seems outlook is malforming and checking the link is safe before actually opening it in the browser which is what is confirming a user before its seen by the user.